# How to run a c++ program if unordered_map is used

Tags: gcc

I have used unordered_map in my c++ program. I complied program successfully by using :
g++ -std=c++0x source.cpp

But after that i have entered **source** to run program but prompt show me that source is not internal or external command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Default output filename is a.out (a.exe on Windows)

Use -o option to specify file name, like this:

```
g++ -std=c++0x source.cpp -o source
```